# How to get Gitzilla working on Windows

Tags: git, bugzilla, pybugz

I've recently installed Git and Bugzilla and was hoping to get some kind of integration going between them.  The TortoiseGit "integration" is useful in some respect but not quite what I'm after.  So, I've been trying to get Gitzilla to work without success.  I've done the following to get closest to getting it to work:

1. Setting up a GIT "central" repository (I was using it in a distributed manner previously).
2. Downloading and installing:

   - gera-gitzilla-gitzilla-2.0-12-g537df1c.zip
   - Python 2.7
   - Pybugz 0.8
3. Copying these files from C:\Apps\Python-2.7\Scripts to C:\Git\Main\hooks:

   - gitzilla-post-receive.exe
   - gitzilla-post-receive.exe.manifest
   - gitzilla-post-receive-script.py
   - gitzilla-update.exe
   - gitzilla-update.exe.manifest
   - gitzilla-update-script.py
4. Renaming gitzilla-update-script.py to update
5. Renaming gitzilla-post-receive-script.py to post-receive

Then, when I committed a change and pushed it to the central Git server I get this error:

```
git.exe push --progress  "origin" master:master

Counting objects: 11, done.
Compressing objects: 100% (6/6)   
Writing objects: 100% (8/8)   
Writing objects: 100% (8/8), 646 bytes, done.
Total 8 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: error: hook declined to update refs/heads/masteror directory
To //<server name>/<share name>/Main
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to '//<server name>/<share name>/Main'
```

(where <server name> and <share name> were removed because they're unique to my systems)

What is the "masteror" directory?  My system only has a "master" file in the "refs/head/" folder.

Is it possible to run this on Windows or is this error unrelated to the OS?

Thanks,
Kevin.

Comment: I guess that `masteror` is a typo. Check your repo on `origin`: go to the `hooks` directory and grep for `masteror`.

Answer (score 1):

GitZilla author here.

I think your terminal is playing tricks on you.

The 'masteror directory' seems to be an amalgamation of 'no such file or directory' and 'hook declined to update refs/heads/master'.

GitZilla isn't really supported on Windows, but I can possibly spend some time on it [buy me a beer? :)]

In any case, once you have the correct error messages (piping to a file might help), I would suggest filing a bug (I use the github issue system).